# definite article or no article with a proper name of a particular workplace

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Should I use the definite article with a proper name of a particular workplace / institution, like in the example below, or is it correct to omit it in this case?

> Workers servicing a steam engine locomotive at (the) Wolsztyn Steam
>   Locomotives Depot

Both options seem correct to me, but I'm not sure. I know the definite article should be used with names of organizations, like "the United Nations", "the European Union" etc., but this is just a proper name of a particular workplace.

Comment: I would say that it has nothing to do with whether you're using a proper name. If this is part of a sentence, use the definite article, but don't use it if this is just a photo caption.

Comment: This is exactly just a photo caption on a stock photography site. So "... at Wolsztyn Steam Locomotives Depot" is correct?

Comment: Then you can choose either option. It's a journalistic convention to leave articles out of headlines and captions just to keep them brief, but you can certainly include them if you want to.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, but I understand that it would be an error to omit the article in "normal" usage, like a sentence in a longer article?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Done. And thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the phrase you've mentioned in your post is part of a sentence, you should use the definite article. You don't need to use it, however, if your phrase is a headline or a photo caption.

If it's a photo caption, you can choose either option. It's a journalistic convention to leave articles out of headlines and captions just to keep them brief, but you can certainly still include them if you want to.